# Touch Bitmap on a Rotating canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I  have to touch the Bitmap on a rotating Canvas.

In my onDraw()

{

```
paramCanvas.rotate(angle, x, y);
 angle+=curving;
```

}

@Override

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 

 {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         float eventX = event.getX();
         float eventY =  event.getY();

                if( MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN <= event.getAction())
            {
```

if (eventX >= x    &&  eventX  <  x +liveAnt.getWidth()

&& eventY >= y  &&  eventY  < y +    liveAnt.getHeight())
 {

```
                        int xDead=x;
                        int yDead=y;



                         }
                         }  

                 return false;
            }
```

I tried the above code but it's not working properly the IF condition is not getting true everytime.

liveAnt is my Bitmap name

canvas.drawBitmap(liveAnt, x,y, paint);

Answer (score 1):

assume you want to draw the bitmap where the center of the bitmap will be at (px,py) canvas coordinates. Have a member variable

`Matrix matrix = new Matrix();`

and in your onDraw:

```
matrix.reset();
matrix.postTranslate(-bitmap.getWidth() / 2, -bitmap.getHeight() / 2); // Centers image
matrix.postRotate(angle);
matrix.postTranslate(px, py);
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, matrix, null);
```

Comment: But Here i have to touch the Bitmap on a Rotating Canvas not on the Bitmap Rotation